# user verification value - where to store

Tags: mysql, database

Quick question as relates to database.

Where would you store the value of "UserVerified"? (The one that occurs after the user has checked his email and clicked on the "Verify" link with the hash value at the end).

Would you store it in the User table? (Along with username, hash) ?

Or in the UserProfile table (along with first name, last name, email, phone, etc) ?

Please note that both tables will always contain 1 entry for a user, such that when a user is created, automatically a userprofile is created as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is all up to your preference. I would figure out what you want it to be more related to, the account as a whole, or to the email address. If it is more related to the account and determines if the account is active, then store it in the User table. If this is more related to the email address and that it is verified, then store it in Profile table.

Again though, especially since the tables are 1:1, it doesn't really matter other than relation and readability.